# Does going prone stack with having cover?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat

Suppose I'm playing a ranged character.  I am standing with an ally between me and my enemies, which grants "+2 defenses" for cover.  I decide to further go prone.  Do I now have a "+4 defenses", 2 from cover and 2 from prone?  Or is "going prone" a 'cover bonus' and therefore nonstacking with the cover bonus from my ally?

Comment: Don't forget that prone also gives *you* a -2 to Attack, and significantly limits your mobility.  So, the question becomes whether the +2 to ranged defense worth it?

Comment: Magic Missile Never Misses :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Prone** gives you:

> You get a +2 bonus to all defenses against ranged attacks from nonadjacent enemies.

**Cover** gives the attacker

> -2 Penalty to Attack Rolls (for ranged attacks)

So against non-adjacent ranged attacks you have a +2 bonus to all defenses and the attacker takes -2 to his Attack.

**Effectively your defenses are 4 higher.**

Comment: Ha! +1: Quicker than me and with a more readable anwer :D

Answer (score 6):

Cover does not grant you a +2 bonus to defenses: it imposes a -2 (unnamed) penalty to attacker's attack rolls.

Being prone grants you a +2 (unnamed) bonus to defenses against ranged attacks from non-adjacent enemies.

So, **against a ranged attack from a non-adjacent enemy you got a +2 to all defenses for taking cover behind your ally and the attacker gets a -2 to hit you because you are prone**.

As a reminder, however, unnamed bonuses stack unless they're from the same named game element.

Comment: "Unless they're from the same named game element".

Comment: Correct. A condition that I remember only when on topic but that is always true. Going to edit. Thanks.

Comment: Minor correction - all penalties are untyped, and therefore stack (unless they are from the same named game element)

Comment: I remember so too. I wrote about bonuses (not penalties) because of I was unsure.